# How to release WatchOS2 app update?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-app-extension, watchos-2, watchos

I have an iOS application with watch OS1 supported app, now I am planning to migrate to watch OS2 app at the same time supporting previous version,

How do I release the app?
Would I have to release the whole app along with iOS app, Watch OS1 and Watch OS2 target? Would I have to change the version number of the iOS app?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new target to release the WatchOS 2 extension. You have everything you need to know to make that migration explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH2-SW1) by Apple. As they point out,

> Because it runs on Apple Watch, a Watch app for watchOS 2 must be completely recompiled into a separate executable.

Your two last questions:

> Would I have to release the whole app along with iOS app, Watch OS1 and Watch OS2 target?

If you want to maintain the support for Watch OS1, then **yes**.

> Would I have to change the version number of the iOS app?

Yes, you would because it is an update. Remember that all the targets must share the same app version and build number

Comment: @coder123 Did you find my answer to be the correct answer? In that case, would you mind setting my answer as the correct one? Thanks!